# HTML How to make a horizontal navigation bar under header

Tags: html, css, navigation, html-lists

I'm creating a website as i'm trying to learn HTML.
I have created a few very basic websites, so I am no master.

My horizontal(top) navigation bar is underneath my header, however I cant center the tabs for some reason.

**How do I get the tabs text to be centered with the nav bar?**

[image]

```
<!--Header-->
<header>
    <img id="pumpkin" src="pumpkin.gif" alt="Pumpkin"> 
    <h2 id="halloween">The Halloween Store</h2>
    <h3 id="goblin">For the little Goblin in all of us!</h3>
</header>

<!--Main Body With Drop Down Navigation-->
<body>
    <nav class="topNav">
        <ul id="topNav">
            <li><a href="HalloweenStore.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="Products.html">Product List</a></li>
            <li><a href="Personal.html">Personal</a></li>
            <li><a href="Ideas.html">Decorating Ideas</a></li>
            <li><a href="Email.html">Join Email</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#topNav {
  width: 790px;
  height: 35px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;}

#topNav li {
  display: inline-block;}

#topNav a {
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: White; }

#topNav a:hover {
  background-color: lightgray}

#body{
  width: 800px;
  background: white;
  border: 5px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  margin: auto;}
```

Comment: Why are you using header outside of the body?

Answer (score 2):

In your CSS file you should do like that:

```
.topNav {
  width: 790px;
  height: 35px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;}

.topNav li {
  display: inline-block;}

.topNav a {
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: White; }

.topNav a:hover {
  background-color: lightgray}

body{
  width: 800px;
  background: white;
  border: 5px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

also `<header>` should go inside `<body>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to center the tabs(li) aligned inside the Nav(ul), Add the ***FLOAT: LEFT;*** CSS to ***"#topNav a"*** element in your CSS file.

```
#topNav a{float:left;padding: 9px 30px 9px 30px !important;}
```

Refer to the below URL.

https://jsfiddle.net/rajeevRF/m1bu4fnr/1/